# Source Control Tab on Vscode not working, stuck with clock symbol, nothing happens

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control

I have been trying to push my changed code to GitHub repo via VScode, it works on GitHub desktop but Source Control tab on Vscode is showing clock symbol forever. Then I do it via GitHub desktop again, but Source Control clock symbol never disappers till I close the application and open it again.
Does anybody have a solution as to why is it behaving like this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Somehow the tracked branch from vscode and the branch I checked out with git in the cli were different.

I could solve the issue by changing the branch in the UI of vscode by clicking on the branch and setting the correct one. I also restarted vscode.

[image]

**Additionally:** make sure you have excluded large folders with small files from git in your '.gitignore' file. E.g. This may happen when you haven't excluded your 'node_modules' folder from version control.

Answer (score 1):

Dont you by chance have the authentication window opened in the background or another monitor?

Comment: C. Koudelka, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33844106)

Answer (score 0):

When I trigger the git commit keyboard shortcut, a COMMIT_EDITMSG window pops up. During this, the source control continues to load indefinitely until that window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to commit your files and vscode stay loading and open COMMIT_EDITMSG, you might be missing a commit message.

Simply write some thing in COMMIT_EDITMSG (not in the lines with #) and save it, or just close COMMIT_EDITMSG and add your message  on top of the commit button.

more infomations can be found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908270/why-does-the-commit-editmsg-open-when-i-try-to-commit-in-vscode)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34806387)